# Contact's birthday event not showing up in google calendar. android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api, android-calendar, android-contentresolver

I use the following code to add a birthday to the contact.

```
String contactName="";
        String contactId="";
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mobileItemEdit.getText().toString()));
        String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID};
        Cursor cursor =
                contentResolver.query(
                        uri,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        if(cursor!=null) {
            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                 contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                 contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID));
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "contactMatch name: " + contactName);
                Log.d("LOGTAG", "contactMatch id: " + contactId);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId);
        values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY);
        values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,  birthdayItemEdit.getText().toString());

        Uri dataUri = getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Inserting the event to the contact works, however, the google calendar does not show up the birthday event.

[image: add event works]
[image]

How to let google calendar show the contact's birthday? any help? thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you add the birthday?  https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact  Birthday isnt an event its their birthday added as a date on the contact created.

Comment: I don't know how to use people API.. My goal is to add a birthday to each contact and can show on the google calendar, maybe the code I found is wrong. any suggest?? thanks

Comment: My suggestion is that you use the Google People api rather than contacts, and add a birthday to the user and let Google automatically add it as an event.

Comment: How the **dataUri** content looks like?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't get the point.. what do you mean??

Comment: I want to see what your request has in it in order to investigate further.

Comment: I update the whole code in the post. please have a look. thank you!

Comment: Just to rule out options, as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event#column-aliases). In this line `values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,  birthdayItemEdit.getText().toString());` what is the value of `birthdayItemEdit.getText().toString()`. Does it have the following format `1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z` ?